# How to splice the wires once the outlet has been removed, and it's not the last item in the circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I removed a GFCI outlet in my kitchen. Capped the black, white, and ground wires. Turned power back on, and I have an entire bathroom with no power. Need to know what to do with the wires in the removed GFCI outlet to restore power to the other outlets in the circuit?

Comment: A photo of the wiring might be helpful but standard daisy chain all the blacks are connected together usually by a wire nut, then the whites all together and last all the bare grounds together.

Comment: How many black, white and ground wires were there?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the load side of the GFCI receptacle in your kitchen was feeding your bathroom.  Assuming the colors were "normal" on the GFCI receptacle - a black and a white to the line side, another black and white on the load side - if this wasn't a bathroom, you might just splice the blacks with a wire nut, splice the whites with another wire nut, and re-energize.

However, if you did that, you'd no longer have GFCI protection in your bathroom, which is a code requirement and an important safety measure.  You'd need to also replace your bathroom receptacles with GFCI receptacles to satisfy the code requirement.

If you have more than one receptacle in the bathroom, you may be able to make the connections so that one new GFCI receptacle in the bathroom protects the other receptacles and / or the other power in the bathroom.

Again make sure at a minimum your bathroom receptacles are protected by GFCI, it's not just a code requirement it's important for safety.

Comment: There's also a Code requirement to have a kitchen countertop receptacle in that location, quite likely.